# How can i prevent changing the image size?

Tags: html, css

I'm facing the problem in size of image.[The related pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEo7c.jpg) When i change the text content , the size of box which image is changed too!!. Here are my HTML code . I'd be grateful to give me help..

Comment: you missed putting your HTML

Comment: Try putting your html and css file for better solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use separate div for both content.

```
<div>
 <img>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a code below. By the way it always happened to me. One solution is knowing the size of the picture and managing the box accordingly. You can also manage to make a `<p>` or `<div>` to keep the text. It will have the same look as you want but your text wont be related with image so image size wont change. Most of html and css stuff is up to you. If you want, you can make perfect designs with only using divs.

Answer (score 1):

You must have set the height attribute to auto. Just give that in px or in percentage.